# Remove last known word in a string

Tags: java, string

How do I remove the last known word in a String?

For example a sentence here,

`"Hello, World. more>>`

I want remove the last word which is `more>>`. This word is known throughout all of my String collection.

Tried using `replaceAll` method, but couldn't make it work.

I also tried `substring` like so:

`person = person.substring(0, person.lastIndexOf(" ")) + " ";`

but it removes the last two words in my sentence. Does regex help?

Comment: If it's removing the last two words, the `" "` (space) may not actually be the delimiter, it could be a "blank" character (such as ASCII 255)

Comment: How do I write the ASCII in the string? Is it `&255;`?

Comment: The first thing I would do is determine if this is the fact.  Print each character of the `String` and use `(int)c` (where c is a `char`) and see what the last blank character actually is (useful if you print the character itself as well ;))

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with regex replaceall capturing group.
See your example:

```
     System.out.println("Hello, World. more>>".replaceAll("(.+)\\s+\\S+$", "$1"));
```

output:

```
     "Hello, World."
```

If you want some explanation you can ask me how this regex works.

Reading again.. You can use directly the following code:

```
     System.out.println("Hello, World. more>>".replaceAll("(.+)\\s+more>>$", "$1"));
```

Noticing that "more>>" is happening throughout all of your String collection, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could write a method like `String removeFromEnd(String, String)` -

```
public static String removeFromEnd(String in, String rem) {
  if (in != null) {
    if (in.endsWith(rem)) {
      return in.substring(0, in.length() - rem.length()).trim();
    }
    return in.trim();
  }
  return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String person = "Hello, World. more>>";
  String toRemove = "more>>";

  System.out.printf("'%s'%n", removeFromEnd(person, toRemove));
}
```

Which outputs

```
'Hello, World.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String removeLastWord(String s,String knownword)
{
    int pos = s.length();
    for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
        {
            if(s.substring(i+1,pos).equals(knownword))
                return s.substring(0,i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I believe what you are looking for is something like this. Start from the end and decrement until you find the space and then see if that is a knownword, if not then keep decrementing
until you find it. If you don't find it then return the original.

However if you have to check from a large quantity of string I suggest using a Set data structure to store in all unique strings so you can access them O(1). This will ensure a run time of O(n) when you call this method

Answer (score 0):

> Tried using replaceAll method, but couldn't make it work.

replaceAll Method takes a Regex pattern, that could have confused you. The signature of the method is as follows:

```
public String replaceAll (String regularExpression, String replacement)
```

The `replace` method should work, and also replaces all occurrences of the string you specify.

```
public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) 
Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified target sequence with another sequence. The string is processed from the beginning to the end.
```

> public int lastIndexOf (String string)

Should also work. Make sure your search strings actually match (maybe the spaces are not really spaces, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace all with a word boundary. this should work

```
String abc = "Hello, World. more>>";
String x = ">>";
System.out.println(abc);
abc= abc.replaceAll("\\bmore\\b"+x,"");
System.out.println(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each word is separated from the other words by a " " then:

```
public String getWithoutLast(String myPhrase) {

    String result = "";
    String [] temp = myPhrase.trim().split(" ");

    //Cycle going from the first word to the word before the last word
    result = temp[0];
    for (int i=1; i<temp.length-1; i++){
        result += " " + temp[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```